# trying to read an XMLfile and only get the data out of one child node using c#

Tags: c#, xml

i am reading from an XML file and it pulls the correct data but pulls the data from 2 different nodes due to repeating of the attributes "server", "database" and "user"
When the program runs, it runs through both rather than just the one node i need it to run through. How can i make it just get the data from the node <MySql_Connection_string/>
The code is as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("xmlConnection.xml");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
{
    string databaseConnection = node.Attributes[0].InnerText;
    if (databaseConnection == "MySQL")
    {
        foreach (XmlElement element in doc.DocumentElement)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.SelectNodes("//MySQL_Connection_string"))
            {
                MySQLServer = element.GetAttribute("Server");
                MySQLDatabase = element.GetAttribute("Database");
                MySQLUser = element.GetAttribute("user");
                MySQLPassword = element.GetAttribute("password");
                Console.WriteLine(MySQLServer);
                Console.WriteLine(MySQLDatabase);
                Console.WriteLine(MySQLUser);
                Console.WriteLine(MySQLPassword);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console.writeline is simply to see the outputs
the xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Database_Connections>
    <MySQL_Connection_string Database_Connection="MySQL" Server="***" Database="littering_detection_jf" user="jordan" password="***" />
    <PostgreSQL_Connection_string Database_Connection="postgreSQL" host="***" username="Jordan" password="***" database="intuvision" Port="***" />
    <SQL_connection_string Database_Connection="SQL" Server="****" Database="anprdb" user="Jordan" password="***" />
</Database_Connections>
```

Comment: Could you also post your XML file, please?

Comment: @KlausGütter done

Comment: Why do you have three nested foreach loops? The inner one would be sufficient.

Comment: @KlausGütter im unsure, when i get rid of the first two / the middle one. the .GetAttribute doesnt work due to it needing an element

Comment: `((XmlElement)child).GetAttribute(...)`

Comment: where do i put this ? are you okay to show me the full forloop, im pretty new to c# / using xml readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all the foreach loops except the inner one:

```
foreach (XmlElement child in doc.SelectNodes("//MySQL_Connection_string"))
{
    MySQLServer = child.GetAttribute("Server");
    MySQLDatabase = child.GetAttribute("Database");
    MySQLUser = child.GetAttribute("user");
    MySQLPassword = child.GetAttribute("password");
    Console.WriteLine(MySQLServer);
    Console.WriteLine(MySQLDatabase);
    Console.WriteLine(MySQLUser);
    Console.WriteLine(MySQLPassword);
    break; // not interested in any additional MySQL_Connection_string elements
}
```

This assumes that `doc.SelectNodes("//MySQL_Connection_string")` returns only XML elements, no other types of nodes which is the case here, so I replaced your `XmlNode child` by `XmlElement child`.